# C# Office 2003/7 Web Components DLL Registry Issue

Tags: c#, dll, registry

I have an issue the system I'm working on, was wondering if any of you can help me.

The system, requires to have the OWC11. But our client doesn't want any installation done with their machine. As countermeasure, instead of installing the OWC11, we just referred to the OWC11.dll. Everything works fine except some of it's function (IE: Graph > Right Click > Data - doesn't show). Upon research, we found out that some registries are needed for it to work. So my question is, given that we can't install anything in the user's machine, is there a way to use the OWC11.dll fully functional without installing the registry needed?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: OWC installation required only on the development machine. Not necessary for deployment. It is applicable for the graph as well. Better, you post the error messages and code which you are trying to execute.

Comment: Hi @Kalyan, thanks for replying. Unfortunately, we can't trap he error, we tried to user the ProcessMonitor, and saw that there are registry items that were not found. So we tried to install them one by one, and it fixed the issue. But we can't do that with the user's machine as they don't allow us to.